# How to access controls within HubSections in Win 8.1 store app? Searching in VisualTree does not work

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am working on a Win8.1 app and the main page uses a Hub. Within each HubSection there are different control that I need to access from Code. The content of a HubSection is not defined directly but by a DataTemplate. Because of this the content cannot be accessed by a x:Name. The following is not possible:

```
<Page ...>
   <Grid>
      ...
      <Hub ...>
         <HubSection x:Name="ListSection">
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:MyListUserControl x:Name="ListControl"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </HubSection>

         <HubSection x:Name="ImageSection">
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:MyImageUserControl x:Name="ImageControl"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </HubSection>
      </Hub>      
   </Grid>
</Page>

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
   // Not possible. Elements within DataTemplate cannot be accessed...
   ListControl.DoSomething();
   ImageControl.DoSomethingDifferent();
}
```

Since the controls cannot be accessed directly I tried to traversed the VisualTree to find the controls manually - as proposed in answers to similar questions:

```
MyListUserControl listControl;
MyImageUserControl imageControl;

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
   FindControls(this);

   if (listControl != null)
      listControl.DoSomething();

   if (imageControl != null)
      imageControl.DoSomethingDifferent();
}

private void FindControls(DependencyObject parent) {
   for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++) {
      DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

      if (child is MyListUserControl) {
         listControl = (child as MyListUserControl);
      } else if (child is MyImageUserControl) {
         imageControl= (child as MyImageUserControl);
      }

      if (listControl == null || imageControl == null)
         FindControl(child);
      else
         break;
   }
}
```

This does not work either, only the MyListUserControl is found. If I log the Child elements the VisualTree looks like this:

```
...
   13: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid
      14: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter
         15: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsStackPanel
            16: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.HubSection
               17: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Border
                  18: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid
                     19: Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle
                     19: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button
                        20: ... 
                     19: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentPresenter
                        20: MyListUserControl
```

The ItemsStackPanel (15) has only one child, the first HubSection with the MyListUserControl in it. No other HubSection is found. At least this is what happens most of the time. It also happens that the first three sections are found. Even sometimes all sections are found.

Thus there is nothing wrong with the search method or the XAML. It seems that the Hub does not load all Sections at once. So, how do I access the controls within the Sections?

Comment: I would try waiting until each section is loaded and search the tree of the Section separately.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, but how to know when the sections are loaded? I could use the Loaded-Event of the UserControls but then the Controls would have to notify the MainPage that they have been loaded. Not really the correct control flow. Additionally the UCs should start some long running tasks as soon MainPage is loaded and not wait until the Hub finally decided to load the sections...

Comment: Those long-running tasks should be done in your ViewModel, with the data ready and waiting for the View to pop in to show them. You should be able to do it at any time, and it likely shouldn't be the UC's which start them (unless they have their own VM).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Loaded event of your own controls and the sender parameter will be the control you are looking for.

```
<local:MyListUserControl x:Name="ListControl" Loaded="ListControl_Loaded"/>
```

Then in the code:

```
private void ListControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     listControl = (MyListUserControl)sender;
}
```

And you can do the same for your ImageControl as well.

Comment: Of course the Hub will eventually create the controls and at this time one can use the controls Loaded event or search the VisualTree to find the controls. Problem is, that one does not know WHEN this will take place. Even in the Loaded event of aHubSections is not certain that the controls within this section have been loaded yet. This is very strange and makes it difficult to handl dependencies between the Hub and its sub-controls.

Comment: Why do you need to know when the controls are loaded? I thought you wanted to find the controls and using the loaded event on the controls it becomes very easy and there is no need to search the VisualTree.

Comment: Each Section uses its own UserControl. Each UserControl loads its own ViewModel. The guidelines say, that the apps splashscreen should be shown until all sections are loaded = show one activity indicator instead of multiple indicators for each section. Problem is that I do not know when the Hub will start creating the sections = the content user controls. Thus I do not know when the controls will start/finish loading their ViewModels. How should I make sure that all ViewModels/UCs are loaded before dissmissing the splashscreen without knowing the UCs?

Comment: I get what you are talking. I have the same situation as well and I am not quite sure when I could start showing the main page. I might go with counting number of sections whose main control (the first child of DataTemplate) have their Loaded event triggered.

Comment: Sure, you could do this, but you will never know when the Hub will start to load its sections. Will it be just after the launch? Will it be when the user starts scrolling trough the Hub due to some virtualization? This could easily lead to a blocking of the app.