# How do I use a button in Windows Phone 8 hub app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to change the context of a button inside a `DataTemplate`, but in my code-behind I can't acses it. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the XAML I am using:

```
<Grid>
    <Hub>
        <HubSection>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Button x:Name="THEbutten" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="186,230,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What code have you tried in your code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Button is inside a DataTemplate, and therefore it is in a different context than the page and not accessible from it's codebehind.

Consider the following options:

1. Modify your Buttons Properties using Data Binding.
2. Create a UserControl for your HubSections Content.

Sadly, the Hub Control is fairly hard to understand and use for beginners, because of this DataTemplate.

Here are some tutorials:

- [Mikaelkoskinen - Getting started](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-hub-control-getting-started-tutorial-semanticzoom)
- [DotNetCurry - The Windows 8.1 Hub Control](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=979)

There are also several questions around here on that topic:

- [How to access controls within hubsections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659179/how-to-access-controls-within-hubsections-in-win-8-1-store-app-searching-in-vis)